# Find the characteristic polynomial of $T(A) = BA$, and prove $T$ is diagonalizable iff $B$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $T: F^{nxn} \to F^{nxn}$ be defined by $T(A) = BA$, where $B$ is some fixed matrix. Find the characteristic polynomial of $T$ (it should have degree $n^{2}$), and prove that $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $B$ is diagonalizable.

I think I've managed to show (1) that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $B$, then $A = (v|0|...|0)$ is an eigenvector of $T$, and (2) that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $B$ iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for $T$. But how to go about ascertaining the characteristic polynomial and diagonalizability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Write the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
  \{&e_{11},e_{21},\ldots,e_{n1},&\\
  &e_{12},e_{22}\ldots,e_{n2},&\\
  &\cdots&\\
  &e_{1n},e_{2n}\ldots,e_{nn}&\}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$
You should find that it is block diagonal.